# How to dynamically create an array and use it in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to create and then use arrays but I need to create dynamically. I'm developing script to get the app pools memory, but when we have more than 1 worker process i need to store in array the memory and then calculate the average.

I'm using this to create it

```
New-Variable -Name "Array_$($AppPoolName)" -Value @()
```

But I don't know how to add data to the array using a dynamic name as I would do it when I use a fixed name (`$var += <Value>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without hashtables and without Invoke-Expression:

```
New-Variable -Name "Array_$($AppPoolName)" -Value @()
( Get-Variable -Name "Array_$($AppPoolName)" ).Value += <Value>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Get-Variable` to retrieve the dynamically named variable e.g.:

```
$var = Get-Variable "Array_$AppPoolName" -ValueOnly
$var += <value>
```

For completeness you can also use Set-Variable but that doesn't directly support array concat syntax e.g.:

```
Set-Variable "Array_$AppPoolName" (Get-Variable "Array_$AppPoolName" -ValueOnly) += <value>)
```

Yeah, that's a spew.  Perhaps a better option is to just use a hashtable:

```
$ht = @{"Array_$($AppPoolName)" = @()}
$ht."Array_$($AppPoolName)" += 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Get-Variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx):

```
$var = Get-Variable -Name "Array1_$($AppPoolName)" -ValueOnly
$var += <Value>
```

Notice `-ValueOnly` at the end. Otherwise you get a variable `PSObject`. From [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx):

> The Get-Variable cmdlet gets the Windows PowerShell variables in the current console. You can retrieve just the values of the variables by specifying the **ValueOnly** parameter...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think the idea is to actually modify the dynamically named array, not assign it to a variable with a fixed name and modify that.

Comment: In order to modify the variable, you first have to retrieve it based on a "dynamic" name into a variable that you then manipulate.  While you could use `Set-Variable`, that syntax is more cumbersome than just using a regular variable.  In general I wouldn't use a dynamically named variable in the first place. I'd more likely use a hashtable.

Comment: If you think about it, doing that is no different than giving it the name **$var** in the first place, because you're creating a dynamically named empty array, then in order to add elements to it, you're assigning that empty array to a variable with a predetermined name and then modifying that. Which in fact makes me rethink my answer...

Comment: Which is why I said I would use a hashtable in the first place.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could first store the dynamic name in a variable, then use **Invoke-Expression** to add to the variable, as follows:

```
$dynamicname = "Array1_$AppPoolName"
New-Variable -Name $dynamicname -Value @()
Invoke-Expression "`$$dynamicname += 'new value'"
```

(Note that you don't need **$()** around **$AppPoolName**; you can interpolate the variable on its own.)

Or, you can use **Invoke-Expression** to re-derive the dynamic name and modify the variable that has that derived name:

```
New-Variable -Name "Array_$AppPoolName" -Value @()
Invoke-Expression "`$Array1_$AppPoolName += 'new value'"
```

Comment: I'm usually pretty cautious about using `Invoke-Expression` as it can be used for script injection attacks. While it is very unlikely in your scenario try this:  put {} around dynamicname in the iex string e.g. ${dynamicname} then set $dynamicname to $dynamicName = "Array_Foo;del foo.ps1 -wh;`$var"  Now execute the iex statement. :-)

Comment: I suppose, but wouldn't it have to be a case where the script takes a dynamic value to use in the variable name that's determined by a human source other than the one in whose context the script is running? Any user who could directly invoke the script and use it for an injection attack could more conveniently sabotage the system at the shell prompt, if he were so inclined....

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it is very unlikely in this scenario.  However, whenever you use iex it is something you should think about.

Comment: It is a good warning to heed, in case of those rare circumstances where a variable passed to **iex** could be coming from a malicious source. In those cases, one could use this as a safety mechanism before the **iex** statement: `if ($variable_to_be_used_in_iex -match '[;>|]') {throw "The value you supplied contains a $($matches[0]) character. What are you trying to pull?!"}` (Add any other potentially abuseable characters to the class)